# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nome')

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, undefined, insomnia

I'm trying to make an API using nodeJS, express and Sqlite and Insomnia for requests. I created the tables and everything worked out, it gives no error, but when I do the POST request by Insomnia, the console returns the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name').

my code for database:

```
import { openDb } from "../configDB.js";

export async function createTable(){ openDb().then(db=>{ db.exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pessoas(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nome TEXT, idade INTEGER)') }) }

export async function insertPessoas(pessoas){ openDb().then(db=>{ db.run('INSERT INTO Pessoas (nome, idade) VALUES (?, ?)', [pessoas.nome, pessoas.idade]) })

}
```

I've redone my code many times thinking it's some syntax error, but I can't find the error.

[image]

Comment: Try logging pessoas.nome and see what it logs. My guess is that it's undefined.

Comment: `personas` is `undefined`

Comment: @justanotherguy returns undefined

Comment: @KonradLinkowski can you tell me how i solve it?

Comment: How do you call `insertPersonas`?